# mysql cannot create foreign key

Tags: mysql

here are my two tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `carslibrary` (   
  `CarID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
  `CarName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,  
  `colorslibrary_ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,   
  PRIMARY KEY (`CarID`),
  KEY `colorslibrary_ID` (`colorslibrary_ID`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `colorslibrary` (   
  `ColorID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
  `ColorName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ColorID`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

I get an error on the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE  `carslibrary` ADD FOREIGN KEY (  `colorslibrary_ID` )
REFERENCES  `cars2`.`colorslibrary` (`ColorID` );
```

MySQL says:

> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint
>   fails (`cars2`.<result 2 when explaining filename
>   '#sql-cf8_41a'>, CONSTRAINT `#sql-cf8_41a_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`colorslibrary_ID`) REFERENCES `colorslibrary` (`ColorID`))

Comment: This can be dangerous as it suggests that a car references a missing color.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your tables aren't empty, therefore a constraint fails (reference not found) when you create it.

Use `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;` and re-run your `alter table`.

Answer (score 2):

I would firstly identify orphaned rows in the `carslibrary` table:

```
select * from carslibrary where colorslibrary_ID not in (select ColorID from cars2.colorslibrary);
```

Then decide what you want to do with these orphaned rows. Want to `DELETE` them from the carslibrary table? `UPDATE` them to an existing parent ColorID in the colorslibrary? `INSERT` a new ColorID in the colorslibrary table to cater for the orphaned rows?

Once you've tidied up your data you should be able to run the `ALTER TABLE` with no errors.